# Search posts by meta key in admin and front

Tags: post-meta, search

i want to search post by meta key and title. but when i use blow code search just meta key. how can i solve that?

```
function extend_admin_search( $query ) {
    $post_type = 'post';
    $custom_fields = array("subtitle");
    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;
    if ( $query->query['post_type'] != $post_type )
        return;
    $search_term = $query->query_vars['s'];

    $query->query_vars['s'] = '';

    if ( $search_term != '' ) {
        $meta_query = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );
        foreach( $custom_fields as $custom_field ) {
            array_push( $meta_query, array(
                'key' => $custom_field,
                'value' => $search_term,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ));
        }
        
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    };
}
```